# Detect pressing or releasing (no pressing and releasing) the headset key on Android

Tags: android, button, release, detect, headset

Welcome to my first question in this forum.

I am building an alarm informing SMS about burglary.

1. I put JACK in the phone.
2. I connect the GND and MIC contacts at the door with a long wire.
3. When someone closes or opens the circuit, the phone sends an SMS.

With the BroadcastReceiver (source code below), I can easily detect **pressing and releasing** the PLAY / PAUSE key on a wired headset. But BroadcastReceiver only starts after **short pressing and releasing** the PLAY / PAUSE button.

I need to immediately detect when the headset key was **only pressed** or just **only released**. The time between pressing and releasing can be very long, for example, a few days. The solution detecting the power interruption of the phone or the sensor on Bluetooth (AT commands), unfortunately, fall off. Android is 4.0.4.

```
    public class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        Log.i ("TAG_MEDIA", intentAction.toString() + " happended");
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            Log.i ("TAG_MEDIA", "no media button information");
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            Log.i ("TAG_MEDIA", "no keypress");
            return;
        }
        Log.i ("TAG_MEDIA", "Yes keypress = " + event);
        }

    }
```

Comment: So you're using an Android phone as a sensor for when a door is opened, by using the mic input to detect changes in a circuit?  This really seems like the wrong tool, Android isn't really a great OS for a sensor.  I'd look into using an Arduino or something like that instead, possibly paired to an Android device via bluetooth.

Comment: Yes you are right. Communication over Bluetooth has already mastered a bit, I can communicate with AT commands using the serial port protocol. I can also detect the connection / disconnection of a USB or AC charger. But I am looking for the very simplest solution, without external additional devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {

        if (status.equals("recording")) {
            txt_recStatus.setText("save recording..");
            stopRecording();
        } else {
            Log.e("headset565656", "record now:");
            //start record
            showTimer();
            recordAudio();

        }
        return true;
    }
```